# методы в с шарпе

Tags: c#

Можно ли вызвать метод после его описания? У меня выходит только вызов а далее его описание.

```
namespace ConsoleApps
{
   class Progrem
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Animal cat = new Animal();
         cat.metod();
         Console.ReadKey();
      }
         class Animal
      {
         public int age = 7;
         public int height = 144;
         public void metod()
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Age:" + age);
            Console.WriteLine("height" + height);
         }
      }
      }
   }
```

<sub>https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxKru.png</sub>

Comment: Покажите как не получается. И да, код выкладывайте текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте код текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: В C# порядок определения классов и их членов не имеет значения. Поэтому не понятно, как именно у вас не получилось разместить определение метода до его вызова, и зачем вообще это понадобилось.

Comment: текст лучше приводить в виде текста, а не картинки. исправить вопрос можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

В C# (.NET) нет разницы сначала описывать классы и методы, а потом делать вызов, либо наоборот.

Программа на C# сначала компилируется в байт код и все классы и функции определяются. Потом происходит исполнение программы, все методы уже скомпилированы и готовы к работе.

Кроме того можно даже такие вещи и не спрашивать, если скомпилируется и запустится, значит всё хорошо. Кроме того много ошибок студия сразу подсвечивает ещё на уровне редактирования кода.

Кстати класс Animal легко можно перенести выше функции Main.

Comment: А если методы вызывают друг друга, как они скомпилируются?

Comment: @АндрейNOP ещё может быть что метод вызывает сам себя )). На самом деле я не вижу проблемы в компиляции таких методов, но и с другой стороны как именно это делает компилятор с полным пониманием и знанием всех моментов, я тоже не знаю, могу только дагадываться. Но, думаю, на уровне этого вопроса это не так важно, когда пишешь первую программу, важно понять как вообще её писать, базу, а не тонкости работы компилятора.

Answer (score -2):

Насколько я понял, ответ заключается в том как работает компиляция,сначала она проходит по полям и вложенным классам и лишь потом попадает в конструктор,в данном случае Main.Так что в любом случае вызов тут происходит после определения.Вот мне стало интересно где вообще имеет смысл и есть ли такое потипа динамическое создание методов во время компиляции..?или тут в сторону анонимных и виртуальных методов, также в LINQ работает похоже,сортировка выполняется при использовании объекта сортировки,а не при описании сортировки.

Comment: Я ничего не понял из вашего ответа. Причем тут компиляция? Почему вы Main конструктором назвали? Динамическое создание типов в c# есть, а вот `динамическое создание методов во время компиляции` - создание чего либо во время компиляции не может быть динамическим. Про LINQ слова отдельно я прочитать могу, но что вся фраза означает я понять затрудняюсь.

Comment: Суть в том что в данном примере программа сначала попадает к описанию метода,а только потом в Main и выполняет его,или я ваш вопрос неправильно понял.

Comment: Вопрос не мой, я просто мимо проходил. Программа начинается с выполнения метода Main, так как метод Main - это точка входа для программы.

Comment: я имею ввиду,перед тем как начать исполнение с точки входа ,то-есть до работы самой программы,компилятор проходит по объявленным типам,и соответственно по описанию метода.

Comment: Я знаю, что вы имели ввиду. Я задавал наводящие вопросы чтобы улучшить ваш ответ, так как в том виде, что он сейчас, из него рядовому читателю будет ничего не понятно.